# android: How does android intent progress

Tags: android, android-intent

I want someone to please explain this to me very simply. I have activities A,B,C,D and D1 which move hierarchically like this. I am passing an intent from A which is the main Activity. When B is called, it receives this intent, when C is called, it also receives this intent. When i call D, i do not need the intent here but D has a list view and on click of an item, it starts activity D1. D1 needs intent from A, remember,D did not call intent from A. My question is this, how do i get the intent from activity A to D1?

Comment: Receive the intent in `D` in the same way you are doing in other activities. Use that intent in `onItemClickListener` of `ListView`

Comment: @jungleboy i tried that but seems like D1 is not receiving the intent. Could it be because D also has it's own intent that i am sending to D1?? D1 sees the intent from D but does not receive the intent from A which i am sending via D.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do one thing, extract all the contents of `Intent` when received in `D` and before passing the new intent to `D`, add these contents to this intent.

Comment: Let me put this as answer then. It will help other readers. Please accept this as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that the correct intent is not getting passed.
Do one thing, extract all the contents of Intent when received in `D` and before passing the new intent to `D1`, add these contents to this intent.